# How do you measure the performance of your Silverlight applications?

Tags: c#, silverlight, performance, profiler

What are some tools/practices used to measure performance with Silverlight?

I am interested in the performance costs of rendering certain xaml objects as well as algorithms I have written.  I was about to start writing my own classes for this, but I thought I would ask here first.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Silverlight Spy 2.  There are Events, Network, and Performance tabs that might give you some of the information you're looking for.

[Silverlight Spy 2](http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/)

Answer (score 1):

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) by JetBrains is a good tool for measuring performance of ASP.NET applications.  Not sure how much it will help you with Silverlight, but will at least analyze your back-end code

Answer (score 1):

There are a few free profilers, [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) isn't bad, which might do what you need. If you can afford it, [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) has become my favorite commercial profiling tool and I expect would do the trick nicely. They have a demo. I do recommend trying all the profilers out there before purchasing any of them, if you have the time, if only to know what you are missing with any particular choice because there are some *substantially* different features among them, and none of them seem to have everything.

Answer (score 0):

Currently,  just build it and then play with it.  Since its client-side as long as its reasonable responsive the job is done.

Comment: Sure, but you might need a tool to help highlight where the problem is, if you notice one.